# Import Module error

Tags: python

i'm trying to test webcam detection with Yolov3 but when i try to convert the yello.weights to Keras with convert.py i have this error:

```
        imed@imed-S551LB:~/Bureau/keras-yolo3-master$ pip3 install keras==2.4.3
    Requirement already satisfied: keras==2.4.3 in /home/imed/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (2.4.3)
    
    Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.1 in /home/imed/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from keras==2.4.3) (1.19.5)
    
    Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from keras==2.4.3) (5.3.1)
    
    Requirement already satisfied: h5py in /home/imed/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from keras==2.4.3) (3.1.0)
    
    Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.14 in /home/imed/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from keras==2.4.3) (1.4.1)

imed@imed-S551LB:~/Bureau/keras-yolo3-master$ python convert.py 

model_data/yolov3.cfg model_data/yolov3.weights 

model_data/yolo_weights.h5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convert.py", line 14, in <module>
    from keras import backend as K

ImportError: No module named keras
```

[image]

But the configparser is already installed !

Comment: What OS? What Pi?

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv ? Does your application use that virtualenv and not the system-wide install of Python ?

Answer (score 0):

Screenshots should be avoided when possible.  Cut & paste of text is preferable in questions.

Perhaps you are using Python 3 and have installed the module for Python 2 or vice versa.

Use pip3 to install modules for Python 3.

Comment: i edited my post but the problem is not solved i use pip3 for installation but i have the same problem